# Postgres - Homebrew Install Cannot Find Server Files Multiple Versions

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I am trying to use `postgres` on my machine and realized that some time ago I had installed the database software after running `brew install postgres` and receiving `Error: postgresql-9.4.5_2 already installed`. From there I decided to install `homebrew/services` to be able to run postgres in the background and successfully launched and closed the background job with

`brew services start postgresql==> Successfully started`postgresql`(label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)`

However, when I run `postgres` I received the error of:

```
postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.
```

When I followed an answer on SO, `cat /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log` I received the following error:

```
LOG:  skipping missing configuration file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.auto.conf"
FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.3, which is not compatible with this version 9.4.5.
```

Which makes me think that I had an older version of PostgreSQL installed that needs to be removed.

I then tried `psql` and received:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

And finally decided to init a new db with `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres`, but that didn't fix it, which resulted in following the original message and setting an env varible: `export PGDATA=/usr/local/var/postgres`. After trying `postgres` again, I receive

```
LOG:  skipping missing configuration file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.auto.conf"
FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.3, which is not compatible with this version 9.4.5.
```

What this tells me is that there is clearly a version compatibility issue, which needs to be resolved in order to launch my postgres server, but I'm not sure what file paths need to be cleared or the proper way to clear them. Can anyone provide some guidance?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I got it to work by running:

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start && brew services start postgresql`

([this guide](https://www.codementor.io/devops/tutorial/getting-started-postgresql-server-mac-osx) was good).